# How to create new column based on value in a set of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df like this:

```
time   a    b    c  
1      0    1    0
1      0    1    0
1      1    0    0
1      0    1    0
1      0    0    1
1      0    0    0
```

I want to create a new column, `df.code` based on the following logic:

- if df.a == 1, return 4
- if df.b == 1, return 2
- if df.c == 1, return 1
- if a,b, or c != 1, return 0

```
time   a    b    c    code  
1      0    1    0     2
1      0    1    0     2 
1      1    0    0     4
1      0    1    0     2
1      0    0    1     1
1      0    0    0     0
```

How do I do this? I'm essentially trying to compress select dummy columns into a multiclass columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should works as is:

stack.csv

```
time a b c
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 0 1 0
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
```

main.py

```
df = pd.read_csv('stack.csv', sep=' ', index_col=False)

df['code'] = 0

df.loc[df['a'] == 1, 'code'] = 4
df.loc[df['b'] == 1, 'code'] = 2
df.loc[df['c'] == 1, 'code'] = 1

print(df)
```

output:

```
       time  a  b  c  code
0     1  0  1  0     2
1     1  0  1  0     2
2     1  1  0  0     4
3     1  0  1  0     2
4     1  0  0  1     1
5     1  0  0  0     0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html#pandas.DataFrame.dot) the dataframe with the codes.

```
df['code'] = df[['a','b','c']].dot([4,2,1])
df
```

Output

```
   time  a  b  c  code
0     1  0  1  0     2
1     1  0  1  0     2
2     1  1  0  0     4
3     1  0  1  0     2
4     1  0  0  1     1
5     1  0  0  0     0
```